# Does the DC create by CreateCompatibleDC need release?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, gdi

If it's necessary, How should I release it? By *ReleaseDC* or *DeleteDC*?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489.aspx) has the answer. Call `DeleteDC` when you are done with the DC.

> When you no longer need the memory DC, call the DeleteDC function. We recommend that you call DeleteDC to delete the DC. However, you can also call DeleteObject with the HDC to delete the DC.

Comment: Use `ReleaseDC` only with `GetDC`.